# Text disappears instead of wrapping when resizing to smaller screen

Tags: css, text, word-wrap

I'm having some trouble trying to make my text wrap when I resize my screen. For some reason instead of the text wrapping as I make the screen smaller, the words start to disappear instead of  wrapping.

js:

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="about-hero">
        <h1> Making your shopping experience more enjoyable.</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.about-hero {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/301930/pexels-photo-301930.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  height: 50vh;
  line-height: 50vh;
 
}

.about-hero h1{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Your code perfectly works for me it didn't disappear

Comment: It doesn't disappear but goes on a second line. Because you have for `.about-hero` style `line-height: 50vh;` it's too much to see the second line.

Comment: @Azu oh I see no wonder I couldn't see the second line

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.about-hero {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/301930/pexels-photo-301930.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="about-hero">
        <h1> Making your shopping experience more enjoyable.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the parent div .about-hero `display: flex`
and make it flexible and align all the child elements horizontally and vertically

.about-hero should look like this

```
.about-hero{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/301930/pexels-photo-301930.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffff;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```